# Android Q, scoped storage

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-scoped-storage

Как известно, в Android Q (API=29) Google в очередной раз изменил правила доступа к внешней памяти (*external storage*) и ввел понятие [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage). Теперь:

> apps that target Android 10 (API level 29) and higher are given scoped access into external storage, or scoped storage, by default. Such apps have access only to the app-specific directory on external storage, as well as specific types of media that the app has created.

У меня есть приложение, в которой используется хранение данных юзера в SQLite БД, которая размещается во внешней памяти. Это сделано умышленно, поскольку по предыдущим отзывам было много жалоб юзеров при сносе приложения уничтожались также данные во внутренней памяти (каталог `android/android/[пакет приложения]/files`). Конечно, в аппе была возможность бэкапа данных и все такое прочее, но юзеры обычно игнорят ее.

В итоге, в свое время я принял решение о хранении данных в каталоге `/Documents`, который возвращался методом `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)`, который в API 29 [обьявлен deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))

**Внимание вопрос:** что мне надо сделать, чтобы достукиваться до БД SQLite хранящейся во внешней памяти посредством обычного `SQLiteOpenHelper` - при условии `android:targetSdkVersion="29"`?

**Update**

Под открытием имеется ввиду использование штатной конструкции:

```
 SQLiteDatabase db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(file.getPath(), 
     null, 
     SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Comment: если я правильно понял - проблема не в том чтобы открыть файл, а в том чтобы до него добраться и открыть, или я не так понял?)

Comment: Открыть его не проблема, вернее получить `InputStream` на него. Проблема, в том, чтобы открыть его посредством `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: а можете показать как вы его открывали до того как гугл нарушили ваши планы если не сложно?) я не уверен что смогу прям точно помочь, но я попытаюсь :)

Comment: см. апдейт вопроса

Comment: то есть загвоздка в этой части `file.getPath()` из-за `deprecated` ?

Comment: Нет, загвоздка в том, что `openDatabase()` не видит файл из-за ограничений `Scoped Storage` - для него он не существует/недоступен

Comment: вы пробовали в манифесте указать `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ` ?

Comment: Это временный костыль, со временем его тоже закроют, в доке есть ссылка на его временность. [The Death of External Storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html)

Comment: ну я вижу два варианта - либо самому впилить нехилый костыль, который будете контролировать только вы, и гугл его не закроет (https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html) либо менять логику программы подстраивая под новые веяния, но может кто-то еще предложит что-то :) я еще поищу в интернетах информацию касательно обхода данной проблемы, если что-то дельное найду то сюда скину :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше уже не станет гугл будет и дальше гайки закручивать, юзай базу в локальном каталоге, а при выходе из активити делай бэкап на флешку через Uri.

Answer (score 1):

В Андроид 10 добавлен атрибут для `<application>`
[`hasFragileUserData`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#fragileuserdata)

> When the user uninstalls an app, whether or not to show the user a prompt to keep the app's data. The default value is "false".

То есть при установленном значении `true` юзеру будет предоставлен выбор удалять ли данные вместе с приложением.
[image: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58750567/15923106]

Конечно хотелось бы большего: какие-никакие настройки (что бы не думать куда пихать временные файлы так чтобы они потом не остались мёртвым грузом и не напугали юзера своим размером) и чтоб галочка была включена по-умолчанию или по выбору...
Эту опцию нужно было добавить давным-давно - многие разработчики в принципе лезли во внешнюю память только из-за её отсутствия.
К сожалению, атрибут никак не влияет на устройства c API старше 29.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в манифест:

```
<application
    ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

Comment: почему закрыли?

Comment: Это временный костыль, который скоро тоже закроют - [пруфлинк](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html)

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar печально. Но этот костыль хоть дает время перейти на новое решение

Comment: Вот и я о том же. Пытаюсь придумать новое решение.