# Как работать с ФС Android на API29+

Tags: java, android

возникла критическая ситуация, дело в том, что Google на API 29 удалил метод getExternalStorageDirectory() через которой работало моё приложение, и запретил загружать в маркет приложения ориентированные на API 28, вот в чём вопрос, как я могу заменить данный метод если мне ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО нужно работать с папкой другого приложения ? Надеюсь на скорый ответ, спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Android Q, scoped storage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069306/android-q-scoped-storage)

Comment: Увы, немного не то, дело в том, что есть некий пакет приложения ( стороннего ), к которому я хочу получить доступ, чтобы загрузить туда файлы (( модов )), т.к разрабатывая приложение мод-менеджер. Но из-за данного ограничения голову уже сломал, ведь механизм с getExternalStorageDirectory() скоро перестанет работать.